# Rails + Paperclip + Amazon S3: SAving images to Amazon but need to process them before and after

Tags: ruby-on-rails, imagemagick, paperclip

I have an app and Im saving the users uploaded images to Amazon S3. However, often users images' are not consistent. And for me to be able to use them in my app they need to be a certain width and height.

Id like to store a basic image in the storage but when using the image within the web app, in different views I need different sizes.

How should I tackle this problem? The challenge is that saving the image and retrieving the image goes directly from app to Amazon S3 without the app being involved.

Any suggestions?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Paperclip allows you to define styles to resize your images after uploading. Refer https://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip/wiki/Thumbnail-Generation